# 'plugin:vite:import-analysis' Failed to resolve import "@mui/styles" from "src\components\Navbar\styles.js". Does the file exist?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite

I'm trying Vite for the first time. Unfortunately, I faced an issue. I'm trying to import `@mui/styles` in `styles.js` file. But it's throwing an error:

[image]

styles.js file:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {

  }
}))
```

navbar.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppBar } from '@mui/material'

import useStyles from './styles'

const Navbar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <AppBar position='fixed'>

    </AppBar>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

In `navbar` component, Vite importing without any issues. How it could be tackled?